# JTree TreeCellRenderer raising issue on showing the selection color

Tags: java, swing, jtree, cellrenderer

I am using this below piece of code:

```
 class CountryTreeCellRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
        private JLabel label;

        CountryTreeCellRenderer() {
            label = new JLabel();
        }

        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            Object o = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
            if (o instanceof Country) {
                Country country = (Country) o;
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(country.getFlagIcon()));
                label.setText(country.getName());
            } else {
                label.setIcon(null);
                label.setText("" + value);
            }
            return label;
        }
    }
```

Since I am passing/returning a label, so on selecting any component in the `JTree`, no selection color is coming.
I tried to use:

```
JComponent comp = (JComponent) super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
comp.setOpaque(true);
if(selected)
comp.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

But if I return `comp`, then the output of the tree is not coming as expected.

How to resolve the same?

**I did not implement any Editor for the same.**

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: +1 for _not_ extending a component :-) It's the job of the renderer to configure the rendering component's visual properties (like, font and colors) based on the parameters passed-in into the getXXRenderingComponent

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500414/treecellrenderer-how-to-set-background-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [source code of the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer-source.html), which extends `JLabel` as well and is perfectly capable of setting a background color. I copy-pasted the relevant lines below:

```
  if (selected)
    {
      super.setBackground(getBackgroundSelectionColor());
      setForeground(getTextSelectionColor());

      if (hasFocus)
        setBorderSelectionColor(UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().
                                getColor("Tree.selectionBorderColor"));
      else
        setBorderSelectionColor(null);
    }
  else
    {
      super.setBackground(getBackgroundNonSelectionColor());
      setForeground(getTextNonSelectionColor());
      setBorderSelectionColor(null);
    }
```

Comment: -1 a) _extending_ a component is dirty design b) mixing calls to super and this is calling for pain (f.i. the infamous color memory in the default table cell renderer)

Comment: @kleopatra I should have made my answer more clear. I wanted to illustrate that it is perfectly possible to obtain the desired behavior by using a `JLabel`, and used the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` as example since it saved me the effort of writing some code. Now that I read my answer again I see it can be misinterpreted

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked as explained by Robin by bit of change basically

```
if(selected){
            label.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        }else
             {
            label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
             //setBorderSelectionColor(null);
             }
```

enough